# AWS-CDK: Why can I not use a Proxy resource in place of an actual resource;

Tags: aws-cdk

AWS Claims, in its [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html), that a proxy resource can be passed as around as a dynamically created resource; However, in my code example below, I'm given an error that the creation of a trigger cannot accept a proxy;

```
nr_ingest_lambda = _lambda.Function.from_function_arn(
    self, "new-relic-log-ingest-lambda",
    function_arn=".........."
)

nr_ingest_trigger = triggers.Trigger(
    self, "nr-log-ingest-trigger",
    handler=nr_ingest_lambda,
)

TypeError: type of argument handler must be aws_cdk.aws_lambda.Function; got aws_cdk.aws_lambda._FunctionBaseProxy instead
```